# Uniform Convergence on Interior implies Uniform Convergence Everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

First, a motivating toy case. Suppose that $\{f_n(x)\}$ is a pointwise-convergent sequence of functions on $[0,1]$ which converges uniformly on $(0,1)$. Then in fact the sequence converges uniformly on the entire interval.

The proof of this is simple. Since there is uniform convergence on the interior, there is some $N$ for which the $f_n$ are within $\epsilon$ on the interior. But since there is pointwise convergence on the boundary, we can find $N_1$ and $N_2$ so that these are also within $\epsilon$. Thus we may take a new $N$ which is just the maximum of these three.

Now in general, this proof won't work. Replacing the interval by some compact set $K$ in a metric space $X$, the interior of $K$ may have infinitely many limit points in its boundary, each with different $N$, so a priori there is no reason to expect that the same kind of argument will work, but I have been unable to find a different one that will.

Because this argument is fundamentally broken as far as I can see, I am skeptical if the claim is even true in general, but I also couldn't find a counter-example.

Comment: Are the $f_n$ continuous on $K$?

Comment: @MichaelLee I don't think they have to be. But if we can prove it in the case they are, that's fine. The toy case is an old exam question, the more general question my own musing.

Comment: @FlybyNight I don't use Reddit, but I know about Tao's blog. Did he write about this question or something similar?

Comment: Assuming that the $f_n$ don't have to be continuous, we can come up with an easy counterexample. Consider any example of $\{g_n\}$ such that the $g_n : S_1\to \mathbb{R}$ converge pointwise but not uniformly to $g$. Let $K$ be a compact set whose boundary is a Jordan curve (with homeomorphism $\varphi : S_1\to \partial K$) and let $f_n$ be defined on $K$ such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly in $\operatorname{Int}(K)$ and $f_n = g_n\circ \varphi^{-1}$ on $\partial K$. Then, we will not have $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $\partial K$.

Comment: @MichaelLee that works more or less like I figured it would, and will accept that if you post it as an answer. It isolates the part that doesn't settle down uniformly since continuity is not required. Perhaps in the case the $f_n$ are continuous, it is true. I will think on it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the $f_n$ do not need to be continuous on $K$, we have a simple counterexample. Consider any $\{g_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, $g_n : S_1\to \mathbb{R}$, such that $g_n\to g$ pointwise but not uniformly. Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\partial K$ is a Jordan curve (and therefore we have a homeomorphism $\varphi : S_1\to \partial K$). Then, let $f_n$ be defined such that $f_n$ converges uniformly in $\operatorname{Int}(K)$ and $f_n = g_n\circ \varphi^{-1}$ on $\partial K$. Then, $f_n$ converges pointwise but not uniformly to $g\circ \varphi^{-1}$ on $\partial K$.

As pointed out by @zhw, if the $f_n$ are continuous on $K = \overline{\operatorname{Int}(K)}$, then uniform convergence on all of $K$ is immediate by taking the limit of $\lvert f(x)-f_n(x)\rvert$ as $x$ approaches $\partial K$.

Answer (score 2):

Simple counterexample: Let $A=\{1/k: k=1,2,\dots \}.$ Define $K=[-1,0] \cup A.$ Set $f_n(x) = 0,$ $x\in [-1,0],$ $f_n(x) = x^n,$ $x\in A.$ Then the $f_n$ are continuous on $K$ and the $f_n$ converge pointwise on $K$ to $\chi_{\{1\}}.$ The $f_n$ converge uniformly on the interior of $K,$ which is $(-1,0),$ but not on the boundary, which contains $A.$

On the other hand, if $K$ is the closure of its interior, and if the $f_n$ are continuous on $K,$ then uniform convergence on the interior implies uniform convergence everywhere. That's simply because every point on the boundary is the limit of a sequence from the interior. So  if $|f_n-f_m|<\epsilon$ on the interior, you'll have $|f_n-f_m|\le\epsilon$ on $K$ by taking limits.